# How to (easily) change Lubuntu applications menu icon

Tags: lubuntu, icons, menu, panel, lxqt

How to (easily) change Lubuntu applications menu icon?

I checked this question here on askubuntu.com, but I could not find any answer.

I am still trying to find a simple way to do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I supposed, this option is already included in Lubuntu for users: fortunately, no files of the system have to be modified and no Terminal command lines are necessary to do this editing.

I found the way by myself after some trial and error. Only then I saw that it is (obviously) also precisely described on the official Lubuntu manual page, [here](https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/5/5.1/lxqt-panel.html).

1. First, find a good icon image you like for your Lubuntu panel and
   save it in your local drive.
2. Then, just go on the panel and right-click on it.

   [image]
3. Click on **Configure Panel**.
4. Go to **Widgets** bar.

   [image]
5. Click on **Menu** or **Application Menu** (it depends on your Lubuntu
   version).
6. Here a new window appears, showing the path of the image file used
   as the menu icon. If you like, you can back up the default path by
   saving it on a .txt file or as a screenshot, for any problems may
   occur or just to recover default settings.

   [image]
7. Now just type the new path for the main menu icon, corresponding to the path of the image you previously saved.

Comment: I find this particular customization quite important, because you use this icon a lot. I also wanted to share this instructions from Lubuntu OS official webpages here on askubuntu.com.

Answer (score 0):

For older Lubuntu versions, you can also simply right-click on the menu icon and the path of the image file used as icon is shown: you can now change it by entering the path of the new image you want to use.